# One way sync in Google accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

I have created a Google account at my work.
I also have my own account on my personal laptop and smartphone.

Now what I want is sync the account at work with my personal account in a way that for example bookmarks, search history, etc transfer from my work account to my personal account, but not the other way.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

You can sign in to Chrome and make a Chrome Profile with one of the accounts. All of your bookmarks, history, etc will be stored on that account. Inside that profile, you can sign in to the other account to access Google apps like Gmail and Drive.

So for example, you log into Chrome with your personal account and then log into Gmail with your work account. You can then click your profile icon to switch between your Gmail inboxes but your bookmarks, history, and other Chrome data will remain tied to your personal account only.